# What is the difference between first law of thermodynamics and Kelvin-Planck statement?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

> What is the difference between first law of thermodynamics and [Kelvin-Planck statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin%E2%80%93Planck_statement)?

Kelvin-Planck statement says that, it is impossible to convert all the heat taken from a source into work. Some heat must be rejected into the sink.

While First Law of Thermodynamics says that, change in internal energy of a body is equal to the difference between the heat exchanged and work done.

> **Since Internal energy of a body can never be negative, does it not implies that all the heat can never be converted into work and the energy left is stored as internal energy of a body?**

Please help me to know, why there was a need of Kelvin-Planck statement when First Law of Thermodynamics was already there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Kelvin-Planck statement says that, it is impossible to convert all the heat taken from a source into work. Some heat must be rejected into the sink.***

You are incorrectly paraphrasing the Kelvin-Plank statement. Re-read the link. Heat can be totally converted to work in a process. That does not violate the Kelvin-Plank statement of the second law. An example is the isothermal expansion of an ideal gas. But it is not possible to have a ***thermodynamic cycle*** whose only effect is to completely convert heat to work. That would be a violation of the Kelvin-Plank statement of the second law. To quote from the link:

“It is impossible to devise a cyclically operating heat engine, the effect of which is to absorb energy in the form of heat from a single thermal reservoir and to deliver an equivalent amount of work ”.

The key phrase you left out of your paraphrased statement is “cyclically operating heat engine”.

***While First Law of Thermodynamics says that, change in internal energy of a body is equal to the difference between the heat exchanged and work done.***

That is correct.

***Since Internal energy of a body can never be negative, does it not implies that all the heat can never be converted into work and the energy left is stored as internal energy of a body?***

No. Again it is possible to convert heat completely into work in a process such that $\Delta U=0$, but not in a cycle. The energy (heat) that is not converted to work in a cycle is rejected to the surroundings in the form of heat. The net work done is the heat added minus the heat rejected. At the end of the cycle $\Delta U=0$ since the system is brought back to its original state.

Consider the Carnot cycle which is the most efficient cycle possible for converting heat to work. It begins with a reversible isothermal expansion that completely converts incoming heat from the surroundings into work. That is followed by a reversible adiabatic expansion ($Q=0$) that brings the system to a lower temperature. Then there is a reversible isothermal compression, which rejects heat to the surroundings. The cycle is completed with a reversible adiabatic compression ($Q=0$) bringing the gas back to its original state. The work done in the cycle equals the heat added during the isothermal expansion minus the heat rejected during the isothermal compression.

***Please help me to know, why there was a need of Kelvin-Planck statement when First Law of Thermodynamics was already there.***

The first law is a statement of the conservation of energy. Converting heat from a single reservoir completely into work in a cycle would not violate the first law since energy is conserved (heat in = work out). However, no heat engine cycle has ever been devised to completely convert heat to work (100% thermal efficiency) from a single reservoir. The Kelvin-Plank statement reflects that fact.

Hope this helps.